# STATIC FILES (CSS NOT FOUND) WITH DJANGO

Tags: css, django

I'm using Django to build a dashboard. The structure of my project is the one below :

```
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│
├───dashboard
│      asgi.py
│      settings.py
│      urls.py
│      wsgi.py
│      __init__.py
│   
│
│
├───projects
│      admin.py
│      apps.py
│      models.py
│      tests.py
│      views.py
│      __init__.py
│ 
│
├───static
│   ├───css
│   │       main.css
│   │       sb-admin.css
│   │       sb-admin.min.css
│   │
│   ├───js
│   │ 
│   │
│   ├───media
│   │
│   ├───scss
│   │
│   └───vendor
│
├───upload_log
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   forms.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   └───__init__.py
│   
└───templates
       about.html
       base.html
       basedraft.html
       home.html
       index.html
       navigationbar.html
       upload_log.html
```

`
My settings are as below :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn') #add


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static/media/') #static/ add


STATIC_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

My problem is whenever I try to use css into my template I get the error "http://localhost:8000/static/css/main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)".

Is there something I didn't understand using static files ? I've through documentation and questions on stackoverflow but I've not been able to fixe the problem.
However, my upload_log application actually finds it's way through static/media/log whenever I use a .csv file to create models...

I had below the html template :

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS and customized CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    <title>DASHBOARD</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    {% include 'navigationbar.html' %}
    <div>
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you append your post by your template,

Comment: I just edit the post with one of the template where I'm trying to implement css

Answer (score 0):

You did not define STATICFILES_DIRS.

The definitions in my project are as follows:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Django Document says

> Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to a particular app. In addition to using a static/ directory inside your apps, you can define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your settings file where Django will also look for static files. For example:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / "static",
'/var/www/static/',
]
```

[Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Ok adding STATICFILES_DIRS fixed the problem. That's was just me thinking that STATIC_DIRS and STATIC_DIREFILES were basically the same... Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: Your welcome, Staticfiles is a general name where static files is.

Answer (score 0):

Your project does not see your static file. If you configure your settings.py file, I think you can solve your problem.

You can try the code below:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
```

Check your TEMPLATES = [..] area because 'DIRS' must contain the template path.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
```

]

Comment: Ok adding STATICFILES_DIRS fixed the problem. That's was just me thinking that STATIC_DIRS and STATIC_DIREFILES were basically the same... Thanks a lot for the help !